# Jquery loop over JSON array with POST/GET reuqest

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Loop over complete JSON array is not executing.

I have tested all the tricks and tried with many changes in my code, but not able to loop over the the complete array.

**AJAX Post to Pull Data**

```
function PullData() {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.pricingindia.in/getlocal.ashx",
                data: '{lat: ' + latitude + ', lon: ' + longitude + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
           });
        }
```

**Loop over complete array**

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
            $.each($.parseJSON(response.d), function (idx, obj) {
                alert("Success");
                alert(obj.StoreName);                    
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Is your success handler firing or is one of your error handlers firing?

Comment: `'{lat: ' + latitude + ', lon: ' + longitude + '}'` will not give you JSON

Comment: I'm not sure how to check console log, any suggestion or screenshot

Comment: success handler firing.

Comment: To check console log just open up your developer tools (usually F12)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData={};
myData.lat=latitude;
myData.lon=longitude ;

$.ajax({
//all your settings
data: JSON.stringify(myData),
dataType: "text" //your .ashx handler returns `text/plain; charset=utf-8`
});
```

Comment: @user3471169, your fiddle itself says problem with `data`. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/kz3Jy/2/

Comment: I was not able to find any problem with data, see data here : http://www.pricingindia.in/getlocal.ashx

Comment: @user3471169, i was mentioned about the `data` parameter that you are  passing in your ajax call. `data: '{lat: ' + latitude + ', lon: ' + longitude + '}'` it is not well formed.

Comment: So, now you formed this data parameter in this fiddle : jsfiddle.net/muralim/kz3Jy/2 but that fiddle still not looping over array

Comment: @user3471169, can you give me some valid value for lon and lat? So i can pass and test the code

Comment: "@LatiTude", 28.605863
"@LongiTude", 77.331227

Comment: OnSuccess is firing, but when i try alert(response.d) :  alert display as undefined. If it's help in debuging